# How to convert ffmpeg command to ffmpeg python code

Tags: python, ffmpeg

How can I convert the below code to python? I'm having issues doing so..

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/Aaron/lol.mp4 -filter:v "crop=9/16*ih:ih" /Users/Aaron/Desktop/lol1.mp4
```

Thank you so much for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

You could have a subprocess call:

```
import subprocess

def crop(input_file, output_file, x, y):
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-filter:v', 'crop={}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])

crop('/Users/Aaron/lol.mp4', '/Users/Aaron/Desktop/lol1.mp4', 9, 16)
```